# Automatically convert WAV files into MP3 files on Mac

Tags: automation, mp3, wav, lame, audio-conversion

Someone already had similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/215938/automatically-convert-audio-files-in-a-certain-folder) but he wanted to convert FLAC into MP3. In my case I want to convert WAV into MP3 and the solution in the other question doesn't help me.

Workflow would be the following: I drop WAV files into folder A, they are converted as MP3 files into folder B. Converted WAV files would be moved into folder C so I would know which WAV files are already converted.

I would like to have full control for the MP3 encoding settings, e.g. bitrate, frequency, channels etc. I guess the best encoder for my purpose would be [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) but I think using iTunes is also ok. I work on Mac. Is there a way to do this automation? I have tried to use Automator but with bad success.

Comment: Does anyone know? :/